# I'm trying to figure out how to calculate if a number is prime or not

Tags: objective-c

ive refined it a bit. Can someone change it to the correct way for me?
i also introduced a new variable isPrime i guess this is a bit better

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        int p = 7;
        int d, isPrime = 0;

        if (p % 2 != 0)
        {
            for (d = 2; d < p; d++) {
                p % d;
            }
                if (p % d == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = 1; //not prime
                }
                if (p % d != 0)
                {
                    isPrime = 2; //is prime
                }
                if (isPrime == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"its not prime");
                }
                if (isPrime == 2) {
                    NSLog(@"its prime");
                }

        }
        else
            NSLog(@"sorry");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Look up the good ol' Sieve of Erawhathisname.

Comment: `d` is uninitialized?

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought I set it to 2

Comment: You're setting it to 2 every time at the top of the loop.  Anyway, this is a pretty inefficient way to check if a number is prime.

Comment: The first time `p < d` is evaluated, `d` is uninitialized. The second time, `d` is 3, and unless `p` is less than 3, your code returns immediately without printing anything.

Comment: A `for` loop is good for this, since you need an initial value for `d`, and you need to check if `d` is less than `p`, and you need to update `d` at the end of each loop iteration.  That's what `for` loops are good for.

Comment: I tried it with this for loop

Comment: for (d = 2; d < p; d++)       didn't work

Comment: That's the correct loop, but the key is that you have to keep track of whether any number `d` divides evenly into `p`, and then print the results after the loop finishes.

Comment: `2` is a prime number :)

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and what you've done to try to resolve the two.

Comment: @josh caswell. expect to happen: its prints "prime". what actually happens: says "succeeded but doesn't do anything. what you've done to try to resolve the two: tried changing the loops and algorithm.. Please help

Comment: @user3734855: The solution to your problem is quite simple: Use a **debugger**. Set a breakpoint in main. Single-step through your program. Inspect the variables and compare them with what you expect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
            int p = 7;
            int d, isPrime = 2;

            if (p % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (d = 2; (d < p) && (isPrime == 2); d++) {
                    if (p % d == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = 1; //not prime
                    }
                    if (p % d != 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = 2; //is prime
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"its not prime");
                }
                if (isPrime == 2) {
                    NSLog(@"its prime");
                }
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"sorry");
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the well-known Sieve of Eratosthenes, but if you are writing a program that is just going to take one number as input and decide whether it's prime, the Sieve does more than you need (it finds all primes less than some value of your choice) so it may not be your most efficient choice of algorithm.

A couple other things about finding primes:

If you find that `p` is not even, you only have to try dividing it by *odd* numbers, that is, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc. (Yes, once you know it's not divisible by 3, technically you know it's not divisible by 9, but it may not be worthwhile or even efficient to account for such things in your algorithm.)

You don't have to try anything larger than sqrt(p) as a divisor. If you haven't found a divisor by then, you never will (except for 1 and p itself).

If you find a number that divides `p`, you can say immediately that `p` is not prime. (You might want to make sure you exit any loops then, too, otherwise you might end up printing the announcement that p is not prime more than once.)

... But you must *never* say that `p` is prime until the end of your algorithm, after all loops have completed. Until then, the most you can say is you haven't *yet* found a proof that `p` is *not* prime.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code for prime number calculation :

```
int num = 11;

NSString * res = null;
for(int i = 2 ;i<num ;i ++)
{
   if(num%i == 0)
   {
     res = @"This is not a prime number";
     break 
   }
 else{
     res = @"This is prime number";

   }

}
```

Comment: FYI it's "pseudo", not "sudo".

Answer (score 0):

Above loop is fine , but you have to start from 3 rather than 2.

Comment: //Tried that but still didn't work 
            while (p < d) {
                d = 3;
                if (p % d == 0)
                {
                    NSLog(@"not prime");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"prime");
                }
                d++;

Comment: Since you want to know if `p` is prime, you try dividing it by numbers `d` that are less than it. `p < d` is the opposite of what you want; you want `d < p`. And a few other things could be improved.

Comment: Thanx so much! what else do I need to improve? I think I am nesting the loops wrong?